# How to fetch data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am executing query like this in zend:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
$resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('db');
$dbAdapter = $resource->getDbAdapter();
$statement = $dbAdapter->query("SELECT * from test");
```

Now `$statement` have `Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli` Object with fetched records in it but I don't know how to get column values from `Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli`. `toArray()` is not working on `$statement`.

Thanks

Comment: @Z0q: Yes, Both `fetchAll()` and `fetchAssoc()` are working. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually obtain any results from your $statement you should do this:

```
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```